# How to disable and enable notification in an app?

Tags: flutter, notifications

I want to make a Focus Based App where once the user enters in the Focus Mode, no social media notification or  any kind of notification will disturb the user.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think by notifications you mean FCM notifications, if that is the case you can simply make a switch that will add/remove FCM token from the backend.

For more info you can check the [Firebase messaging package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) on pubdev